# Editing system files in Linux (as root) with GUI and CLI text editors #3

Tags: linux, posix, sh, text-editor

One year and a half ago I posted the second iteration of this script for a review here:

[Editing system files in Linux (as root) with GUI and CLI text editors #2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/236530/104270)

---

Since then, it has been "hibernated" as I had way too much work, and I would like to ask you for a review of the possible final edit. I made a big effort for it to be final, but we all know there is always some space to improve. Thank you in advance!

As stated in there:

> My intention is to POSIX-ly write one generalized function for running various text editors I use for different purposes through `sudoedit`, i.e. editing files as root safely. Safely = for instance, if a power loss occurs during the file edit; another example could be lost SSH connection, etc.

---

### The script follows

```
#!/bin/sh

# Please, customize these lists to your preference before using this script!
cli_editors='vi nano'
gui_editors='subl xed'

# NON-COMPLIANT: code -w --user-data-dir; I did not find a way to run it through `sudoedit`;
# atom -w --no-sandbox; gedit -w does not work via rooted ssh; pluma does not have -w switch


# USAGE INSTRUCTIONS

# 1. Customize the editor lists at the beginning of this script.
#
# 2. Bash: Source this script in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases with:
# . /full/path/to/sudoedit-enhanced
# Other shells: Generally put it inside your shell's startup config file...
#
# 3. Call an alias, for instance, one CLI, and one GUI editor:
# sunano /path/to/file
# susubl /path/to/file
#
# Explanation: This script works with standard `sudoedit`, but
# it does a bit more checks and allows some GUI editors to be used.
# It needs to be sourced into your shell's environment first.
# Then simply use the pre-defined aliases or define some yourself.

sudoedit_err ()
{
    printf >&2 '%s\n' 'Error in sudoedit_run():'
    printf >&2 '%b\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

sudoedit_run ()
{
    # print usage
    if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
        printf >&2 '%s\n' 'Usage example: sunano /file1/path /file2/path'
        exit 1
    fi

    # sudo must be installed
    if ! command -v sudo > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        sudoedit_err "'sudo' is required by this function. This is because" \
        "'sudoedit' is part of 'sudo'\`s edit feature (sudo -e)"
    fi

    # the first argument must be an editor type
    case "$1" in
        ('cli'|'gui') ;;
        (*) sudoedit_err "'$1' is unrecognized editor type, expected 'cli' or 'gui'." ;;
    esac

    # store editor's type and name and move these two out of argument array
    editor_type=$1; editor_name=$2; shift 2

    # find and store path to this editor
    editor_path=$( command -v "$editor_name" 2> /dev/null )

    # check if such editor = executable path exists
    if ! [ -x "$editor_path" ]; then
        sudoedit_err "The '$editor_name' editor is not properly installed on this system."
    fi

    # `sudoedit` does not work with symlinks!
    # translating symlinks to normal file paths using `readlink` if available
    if command -v readlink > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        for file in "$@"; do
            if [ -L "$file" ]; then
                if ! file=$( readlink -f "$file" ); then
                    sudoedit_err "readlink -f $file failed."
                fi
            fi
            set -- "$@" "$file"
            shift
        done
    fi

    if [ "$editor_type" = gui ]; then
        # 1. GUI editors will "sit" on the terminal until closed thanks to the wait option
        # 2. Various editors errors might flood the terminal, so we redirect all output,
        #    into prepared temporary file in order to filter possible "sudoedit: file unchanged" lines.
        if tmpfile=$( mktemp /tmp/sudoedit_run.XXXXXXXXXX ); then
            SUDO_EDITOR="$editor_path -w" sudoedit -- "$@" > "$tmpfile" 2>&1
            grep 'sudoedit:' "$tmpfile"
            rm "$tmpfile"
        else
            sudoedit_err "mktemp /tmp/sudoedit_run.XXXXXXXXXX failed."
        fi
    else
        # 1. CLI editors do not cause problems mentioned above.
        # 2. This is a generic and proper way using `sudoedit`;
        #    Running the editor with one-time SUDO_EDITOR setup.
        SUDO_EDITOR="$editor_path" sudoedit -- "$@"
    fi
}

sudoedit_sub ()
{
    ( sudoedit_run "$@" )
}

# Editor aliases generators:
# - avoid generating editors aliases for which editor is not installed
# - avoid generating editors aliases for which already have an alias

for cli_editor in $cli_editors; do
    if command -v "$cli_editor" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # shellcheck disable=SC2139,SC2086
        if [ -z "$( alias su$cli_editor 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
            alias su$cli_editor="sudoedit_sub cli $cli_editor"
        fi
    fi
done

for gui_editor in $gui_editors; do
    if command -v "$gui_editor" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # shellcheck disable=SC2139,SC2086
        if [ -z "$( alias su$gui_editor 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
            alias su$gui_editor="sudoedit_sub gui $gui_editor"
        fi
    fi
done

unset cli_editors gui_editors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from your self-review, I noticed a few (*very* minor) things I thought may be worth pointing out

First, a design opinion rather than a comment on the code. I'm not sure putting the lists of editors in variables in the file is the best approach - it has its advantages, but allowing it to be managed separately in configuration files may have advantages. Were I a user of this script I would prefer to be told to go edit something like a `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/sudoedit-enhanced` file over being encouraged to edit the script itself

It feels a bit weird to have `sudoedit_run` print `sunano` as a usage example regardless of whether nano is desired, or available. Would it be at all realistic to offer up one of the aliases that were successfully defined?

While you can *usually* assume `/tmp` exists, the user may prefer to store their temp files elsewhere. Consider having the `mktemp` call instead use the `--tmpdir` flag to create a file relative to the `$TMPDIR` set by the user - not many users will care, but those who do will probably have very strong feelings about it

The alias generators act a bit weird on editors whose names contain spaces - which binary files *can* even if they rarely *do*. Right now, as you store each editor as a word in a space-separated string you really *can't* worry about what to do with them, but if you were to some day end up refactoring something in such a way that it becomes possible to do something funky like `cli_editor="per se"`, consider how a line like `su$cli_editor="sudoedit_run cli $cli_editor"` would react to that (it's *sometimes* but *not always* an error, and there might be side effects). Quoting the alias name, to force a failure due to an invalid alias name (at least in bash, not sure if other shells permit spaces in alias names) might be preferable

`sudoedit_run` also has a subtle bug in how it checks for an editor - `command -v` will report the name of shell builtins in favor of commands. If someone were to do something silly like listing `echo` as an editor, `command -v echo` would return `echo`. This would lead to it working just fine as long as there's a file called `echo` in your current directory, but get reported as not properly installed otherwise. It's enough of a corner case that it's almost certainly not worth caring about, but still

Answer (score 1):

1. The print error function is only useful to a point, I have rather removed it and used direct in-place constructs instead, so this function has been removed:

   ```sh
   sudoedit_err () { ... ; exit 1; }
   ```

   and the code had changed to this:

   ```sh
   printf >&2 '%s\n' '...'
   return 1
   ```

   So, it is now without the useless headline, and also we eliminated the `exit` keyword completely. In all of the code `return` is used now. Also there is now no need for `'%b\n'` in `printf` as there are no escape sequences like Tab or New line.
2. Thanks to the above change it was possible to remove the subshell function:

   ```sh
   sudoedit_sub ()
   {
       ( sudoedit_run "$@" )
   }
   ```
3. The *print usage* routine now returns 0 exit code, as it seems more logical to me if someone just hits the alias without any argument like with `nano`:

   ```sh
   sunano
   ```
4. New opening routine added to address the issue when someone would try to hit `sudoedit_run` with 0 or 1 argument:

   ```sh
   if [ "$#" -le 1 ]; then
       printf >&2 '%s\n' 'Implementation example: sudoedit_run cli nano /path/to/file'
       return 1
   fi
   ```
5. Finally, there was an unseen error in the GUI editor routine, where it would always return 0 exit code, no matter how `sudoedit` would end up, this is now corrected:

   ```sh
   if [ "$editor_type" = 'gui' ]; then
       # 1. GUI editors will "sit" on the terminal until closed thanks to the wait option
       # 2. Various editors errors might flood the terminal, so we redirect all output,
       #    into prepared temporary file in order to filter possible "sudoedit: file unchanged" lines.
       if tmpfile=$( mktemp /tmp/sudoedit_run.XXXXXXXXXX ); then
           SUDO_EDITOR="$editor_path -w" sudoedit -- "$@" > "$tmpfile" 2>&1
           exit_code=$?
           grep 'sudoedit:' "$tmpfile"
           rm "$tmpfile"
           return "$exit_code"
       else
           printf >&2 '%s\n' "mktemp /tmp/sudoedit_run.XXXXXXXXXX failed."
           return 1
       fi
   else
       ... CLI routine ...
   fi
   ```

---

The refactored code follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|                        Safe text files editing as `root`                     |
#|                          Language: POSIX shell script                        |
#|                     Copyright: 2020-2021 Vlastimil Burian                    |
#|                      M@il: info[..]vlastimilburian[..]cz                     |
#|                               License: GPL 3.0                               |
#|                                 Version: 2.1                                 |
#|                         GitHub: https://git.io/Jvnzq                         |
#+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

# Customize these lists to your preference before using this script!
cli_editors='vi nano'
gui_editors='subl xed'

# NON-COMPLIANT-GUI:
#    - code -w --user-data-dir; I did not find a way to run it through `sudoedit`
#    - atom -w --no-sandbox
#    - gedit -w does not work via rooted ssh
#    - pluma does not have -w switch

# USAGE INSTRUCTIONS
#
# 1. Customize the editor lists at the beginning of this script.
#
# 2. Bash: Source this script in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases with:
#    source /full/path/to/sudoedit-enhanced
#
# Other shells: Put it inside your shell's startup config file universally using dot:
#    . /full/path/to/sudoedit-enhanced
#
# 3. Call an alias, for instance, one CLI, and one GUI editor:
#
# sunano /path/to/file
# susubl /path/to/file
#
# Explanation: This script works with standard `sudoedit`, but
# it does a bit more checks and allows some GUI editors to be used.
# It also allows symbolic links be translated into ordinary files.
# It needs to be sourced into your shell's environment first.
# Then simply use the pre-defined aliases or define some yourself.

sudoedit_run ()
{
    # print error if called with 0 or 1 argument
    if [ "$#" -le 1 ]; then
        printf >&2 '%s\n' 'Implementation example: sudoedit_run cli nano /path/to/file'
        return 1
    fi

    # print usage if called with 2 arguments
    if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' 'Usage example: sunano /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2'
        return 0
    fi

    # sudo must be installed
    if ! command -v sudo > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf >&2 '%s\n' "'sudo' is required by this function. This is because" \
                          "'sudoedit' is part of 'sudo'\`s edit feature (sudo -e)."
        return 1
    fi

    # the first argument must be an editor type
    case "$1" in
        ('cli'|'gui')
        ;;
        (*)
            printf >&2 '%s\n' "'$1' is unrecognized editor type, expected 'cli' or 'gui'."
            return 1
        ;;
    esac

    # store editor's type and name and move these two out of argument array
    editor_type=$1; editor_name=$2; shift 2

    # find and store path to this editor
    editor_path=$( command -v "$editor_name" 2> /dev/null )

    # check if such editor = executable path exists
    if ! [ -x "$editor_path" ]; then
        printf >&2 '%s\n' "The '$editor_name' editor is not properly installed on this system."
        return 1
    fi

    # `sudoedit` does not work with symlinks!
    # translating symlinks to normal file paths using `readlink` if available
    if command -v readlink > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        for file in "$@"; do
            if [ -L "$file" ]; then
                if ! file=$( readlink -f "$file" ); then
                    printf >&2 '%s\n' "readlink -f $file failed."
                    return 1
                fi
            fi
            set -- "$@" "$file"
            shift
        done
    fi

    if [ "$editor_type" = 'gui' ]; then
        # 1. GUI editors will "sit" on the terminal until closed thanks to the wait option
        # 2. Various editors errors might flood the terminal, so we redirect all output,
        #    into prepared temporary file in order to filter possible "sudoedit: file unchanged" lines.
        if tmpfile=$( mktemp /tmp/sudoedit_run.XXXXXXXXXX ); then
            SUDO_EDITOR="$editor_path -w" sudoedit -- "$@" > "$tmpfile" 2>&1
            exit_code=$?
            grep 'sudoedit:' "$tmpfile"
            rm "$tmpfile"
            return "$exit_code"
        else
            printf >&2 '%s\n' "mktemp /tmp/sudoedit_run.XXXXXXXXXX failed."
            return 1
        fi
    else
        # 1. CLI editors do not cause problems mentioned above.
        # 2. This is a generic and proper way using `sudoedit`;
        #    Running the editor with one-time SUDO_EDITOR setup.
        SUDO_EDITOR="$editor_path" sudoedit -- "$@"
    fi
}

# Editor aliases generators:
# - avoid generating editors aliases for which editor is not installed
# - avoid generating editors aliases for which already have an alias

for cli_editor in $cli_editors; do
    if command -v "$cli_editor" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # shellcheck disable=SC2139,SC2086
        if [ -z "$( alias su$cli_editor 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
            alias su$cli_editor="sudoedit_run cli $cli_editor"
        fi
    fi
done

for gui_editor in $gui_editors; do
    if command -v "$gui_editor" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        # shellcheck disable=SC2139,SC2086
        if [ -z "$( alias su$gui_editor 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
            alias su$gui_editor="sudoedit_run gui $gui_editor"
        fi
    fi
done

unset cli_editors gui_editors cli_editor gui_editor
```